# Override color derived from <span> tag

Tags: colors, overriding, html

Is there a way to override color derived from a CSS class in  tag.

Background:
 I am working in a packaged environment (ERP) and I have a need to customize colors for Table columns -  e.g. Green if Number is between 0 to 100, Blue if 100-200 etc.
 The standard out of box for this software has grouped all numbers under one class called "NUMBER" and  below is the line of code that is generated .

```
<span class="NUMBER" title="550">550</span>
```

The only thing I can change through customizing  is the value (550) and I would like to know if there is any way I can override the Color that is derived from "NUMBER" class.

Thank you for looking int this.

Regards, 
Aarpi.

Comment: Can you add a style attribute to the span element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style` attribute. E.g.

```
<span class="NUMBER" title="550" style="color:#0000FF;">550</span>
```

Basically, you can override any property defined in the class.

Or you can change contents like this:

```
<span class="NUMBER" title="550"><span style="color:#0000FF;">550</span></span>
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your quick response . Because of the vendor's restrictions on the code I cannot change any attributes on the <SPAN> tag, I only have a flexibility to change the value .

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky The <font> element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

Insert another span with the desired attributes

Comment: Thanks Daneze, thats a nice idea. I tried this and it works, thanks.